# [Error]: object not found for update Swift + Parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Class Name : Product
Column Name : Likes

i print 1 and 2 just for check

```
var objectID = "wbgNSvui5b" //object are exist in my database

var query = PFQuery(className:"Product")
 var P =   query.getObjectWithId(objectID)
              P.incrementKey("Likes")
P.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        println("1")
        // The score key has been incremented
    } else {
        println("2")

        // There was a problem, check error.description
    }
}
```

always print 2 with object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.4)

Comment: You probably have issues with authentication. Do you have `PFUser` in your app?

Comment: Also make sure the objectId and class name are exactly correct. Is the get statement succeeding?  Or is no object ever found?

Comment: @egor.zhdan Yes i logged in before this page . and i check.

Comment: @milesper The object is correct because i can get value P object before i increment it

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can do a line break in your closure syntax between your method name and the return values (I think the `in` needs to be the last thing before the line break). Maybe you just formatted your code for Stack Overflow, but just thought I'd mention this:

```
P.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if success{
    println("success")
  }else{
    println(error!.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```

Good luck. :)

Comment: That's not correct. I routinely put the closure block on the next line.

Comment: Is that true for previous versions of Swift? The language has changed a lot since June 2015.

Comment: The line break was allowed in Swift 1 as well.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for letting me know.